# Erythritol oxidation using acidified KMnO4

Tags: experimental-chemistry, synthesis, organic-oxidation, carboxylic-acids

I have recently experimented with erythritol oxidation my primary aim was to make glyoxal. However regarding the nature and structure of erythritol several other side-products were also observed one of them which I have confirmed to be oxalic acid using FeCl3 solution which precipitated ferric oxalate which was kind of dirty green in color. carbon dioxide was also seen to be evolved which was most probably from the decarboxylation of beta-keto acid which on paper seems to be a non-planar derivative of dioxobutanedioic acid
[image]

however due to the nature of the compound erythritol several other oxidation products are also possible which among which glyoxal seems to be present in minimal or negligible amounts
[image: notice the structure of the compound which has bonds which extend both inside and outside the plane]
notice the structure of the compound which has bonds which extend both inside and outside the plane.  My question is what other compounds can be formed in the reaction? and if possible how to detect them and is it possible to make and extract a compound like dioxobutanedioic acid or glyoxal from erythritol oxidation with common oxidizing agents found in a lab setting.

Comment: Dioxobutanedioic acid would be hydrated.

Comment: i think that it would be decarboxylated as its a beta keto acid but please elaborate what you mean

Comment: :/ I you got it, it would be in gem-diol form, like glyoxal itself.

Comment: i have anticipated that but there is a large possibility of formation of byproducts like oxalic acid which i have confirmed to be present in solution since i want a fairly pure solution of glyoxal i wanna know about other byproducts